# Powershell sql insert error data will be truncated removed data and still get error

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sqlcmd, truncated

I have a powershell script that I am trying to use to write data from a source .txt to an SQL table

```
Import-Csv $_.fullname -Header Z_AP_EXNUM,Z_AP_ID | ForEach-Object {Invoke-Sqlcmd `
        -Database $database -ServerInstance $server -Username $uid -Password $pwd `
        -Query "insert into $table VALUES ('$_.Z_AP_EXNUM','$_.Z_AP_ID')"
```

My actual code has about 293 headers/columns to insert. The error I receiving is that String or binary data will be truncated. The statement has been terminated. I went into one of my test files and removed all the data but a few standard fields and still receive these errors. I am not sure what could be causing the insert to fail.

Error:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.
>   At C:\Users***\Desktop\script\scripy.ps1:79 char:111
>   +         Z_AP_STR_CSEM5_9,Z_AP_STR_NAME5_10,Z_AP_STR_SCOR5_10,Z_AP_STR_CSEM5_10 | ForEach-Object {Invoke-Sqlcmd <<<<  `
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the table schema, this error usually shows due to the difference of column definition type in the table and the powershell data type you want to store in it.

Comment: Ive been looking over the fields and all the data types seem to be consistent, I removed all the data from one test file except for a simple number field and still got the same error, not sure if the field being empty is causing the issue.

Comment: Is my syntax on the query correct, or am I passing the literal field name because of the quotes.

Comment: I figured it out, it was syntax error with the query, I believe it was passing the literal. I changed my code to escape the quotes and assigned the headers to vars and its working now. similarly to                                                                   "insert into $table (filename, size) VALUES     (`'$Name`',` '$FileSize`')"
}